dealii cmake Configuration error: Cannot compile a test program with the final set of compiler and linker flags
I am trying to install dealii library in Windows.
I follow the instructions specified on the dealii github. But when run
cmake -G "Visual Studio 17 2022" -A x64 ..

I got the following error:
CMake Error at cmake/setup_finalize.cmake:126 (message):


    Configuration error: Cannot compile a test program with the final set of
    compiler and linker flags:
      CXX flags (RELEASE): /EHsc /bigobj /O2
      LD flags  (RELEASE):
      LIBRARIES (RELEASE): ;




Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/macros/macro_verbose_include.cmake:19 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:123 (verbose_include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

The following is the content at line 126 of the cmake/setup_finalize.cmake file.
 if(NOT DEAL_II_HAVE_USABLE_FLAGS_${build})
    message(FATAL_ERROR "
  Configuration error: Cannot compile a test program with the final set of
  compiler and linker flags:
    CXX flags (${build}): ${DEAL_II_CXX_FLAGS} ${DEAL_II_CXX_FLAGS_${build}}
    LD flags  (${build}): ${DEAL_II_LINKER_FLAGS} ${DEAL_II_LINKER_FLAGS_${build}}
    LIBRARIES (${build}): ${DEAL_II_LIBRARIES};${DEAL_II_LIBRARIES_${build}}
  \n\n"
      )
  endif()

How to fix that error?
I have Visual Studio 2022 installed.

I don't have an answer for you but the website implies that Windows isn't really a platform that they support (Issue 1921 says 4 of 13 tasks to complete Windows support are done). You can try installing an older version of Visual Studio (they mention 2017 and 2019) and see if that works, but it may be best to ask on their github page.
